# "On Client" DataTable SQL Query

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access, ado.net

I'm running a sql query against several instances of our WCMS software that all have a fairly uniform schema but live on unconnected sql server instances. I need to run a query against all instances to generate one datatable and run a query against this aggregate table. Basically a .net/sql flavor of a map-reduce query.

I have accomplished the first part, I can run the query against all instances and aggregate that into one DataTable. But I'm not sure how to then run a reduce query on that table. I do not believe ado.net has a method of running sql queries against a datatable. (hopefully i'm wrong on that part?) One method I've considered is inserting the datatable as a temp table into one of the sql server instances then running the query against it, but that seems wrong. I'd rather the reduce is run on the client side (a console app that ultimately spits out a csv file).

I'm wondering if there's a way to finagle Access/Jet into being my temp client-side db that i can query...

Comment: So you can't replicate your desired SQL using a linq query for example?  Alternatively you could use a local SQL Server instance, link it to the remotes then you have it all in one SQLish place.

Comment: @AlexK. I want the map and reduce queries to be command line parameters. I couldn't find a way to parse sql to a linq expression.

Comment: Well... Access can import data from SQL Server, of course. Access can even run queries against unimported data from multiple different SQL server instances, without first importing them. However, I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Have you tried anything you're struggling with?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth What I'm struggling with is DataTable => SQL Query => DataTable and all in a windows console app.

Comment: Why is it in a datatable in the first place? Query before you put things in datatables.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm creating an aggregate table from a query run against thousands of databases (mapping) then want to aggregate the result of that (reduce)

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to do that in Access, do that in Access. Don't first move it to a data table, then to access, and then to a data table. Just map in Access.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth because I have to look up the thousands of db ips/credentials from yet another database.

Answer (score 0):

This function seems to work

```
    private static DataTable query_as_table(string[] columns, DataRow[] rows, string sql)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

        File.Delete(fileName);

        var tempConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + fileName +
                                   "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";
        var cat = new Catalog();
        cat.Create(tempConnectionString);
        var table = new Table();
        table.Name = "mapped";

        var datatable = new DataTable();

        foreach (var col_name in columns)
        {
            table.Columns.Append(col_name);
            datatable.Columns.Add(col_name);
        }
        foreach (var data_row in rows)
        {
            datatable.ImportRow(data_row);
        }
        foreach (var data_row in datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
        {
            data_row.AcceptChanges();
            data_row.SetAdded();
        }
        cat.Tables.Append(table);


        var conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = tempConnectionString;
        conn.Open();

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from mapped", conn);

        var cbr = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        cbr.QuotePrefix = "[";
        cbr.QuoteSuffix = "]";
        cbr.GetInsertCommand(true);
        adapter.Update(datatable);

        var adapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adapter2.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();

        var resultTable = ds.Tables[0];
        return resultTable;
    }
```